# How to keep exisiting sqlite databse in Android and Eclipse??

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

I have sqlite database, I want to use this and fetch the data from table. But how to keep database in android and eclipse.? Means how to use this existing database? Please help me

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from the following link

http://limbaniandroid.blogspot.in/2013/02/useing-your-sqlite-database-in-android.html

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/